# How to view golden ratio guides in Photoshop without crop tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to view the golden ratio guide lines in Photoshop without using the crop tool? I'd like to use the guides for aligning objects, not cropping.

Comment: always worth noting: That the golden ratio is 'particularly pleasing' and has aesthetic value is mostly just an presumption not backed up with any real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your own. You can add guides in Photoshop by dragging them from the rulers. If you don't see the rulers, hit <kbd>View > Rulers</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Alternatively, use <kbd>View > New Guide...</kbd> and key in the height or width you want the guide to appear at. If you multiply your document's height and width by .39 and .61, you get the places you want your guides to be at.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw your own but tools like PhiMatrix make it much easier and offer far more variations. If you draw your own, the correct proportions are .618 and .382.